# Ubuntu 10.10 for APC 8750

Tags: custom-distributions

I am using ACP 8750 running on ARMv6, which runs on Android 2.3 and optional boot from SD card to Raspbian OS.

My question is can you build custom Ubuntu 10.10 that I can boot using my APC 8750?

Comment: Ubuntu 10.10 ? Its already in EOL list.you'd better move with Latest versions like Ubuntu 12.04LTS or Ubuntu 12.10 from www.ubuntu.com

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not going to get an Ubuntu.

However there is an [APC version of Raspbian](http://www.raspbian.org/ApricotImages) that could work for you:

regards

Nico